# SwipeRefreshLyout not Working Properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

So I have `Fragment` that is supposed to fetch some data from Internet using `RecyclerView` i want to add the Swipe Refresh Gesture to my Fragment so the user can check out if any new piece of data is on . 
Here is my code :

Fragment :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

RecyclerView recyclerView;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    swipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recylerview);

    ReadRss readRss = new ReadRss(getContext(), recyclerView);
    readRss.execute();


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    new ReadRss(getContext(), recyclerView).execute();
    if(swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

}
}
```

XML Layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.essat.essat.HomeFragment"
    >


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recylerview"
        />

>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The Problem is that the `SwipeRefreshLayout` never stops turning even with this piece of code :

```
if(swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

I Hope someone knows how to fix this , Thank You :)

**UPDATE** :

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
Context context;
String address = "http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news_current.xml";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
URL url;
ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
RecyclerView recyclerView;


public ReadRss(Context context,RecyclerView recyclerView  ) {
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
    this.context = context;

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    ((IWithHttpRequest) context).onDataUpdate();
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(context, feedItems);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpace(20));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ProcessXml(Getdata());
    return null;
}

private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
    if (data != null) {
        feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
        Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items = channel.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Node cureentchild = items.item(i);
            if (cureentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                FeedItem item=new FeedItem();
                NodeList itemchilds = cureentchild.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < itemchilds.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node cureent = itemchilds.item(j);
                    if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                        item.setTitle(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                        item.setDescription(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                        item.setPubDate(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                        item.setLink(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")) {
                        String url = cureent.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
                        item.setThumbnailUrl(url);
                    }
                }
                feedItems.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

public Document Getdata() {
    try {
        url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Fragment Updated :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener,IWithHttpRequest{


public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

RecyclerView recyclerView;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    swipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recylerview);

    ReadRss readRss = new ReadRss(getContext(), recyclerView);
    readRss.execute();


    return view;
}



@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    new ReadRss(getContext(), recyclerView).execute();


}


@Override
public void onDataUpdate() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
}
```

Comment: swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
and in onPostExecute call 
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot this in **onCreateView**

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```

Also, `new ReadRss(getContext(), recyclerView).execute();` is asynchronous, or at least should be (**don't block the UI thread**), so the it will look like the refresh is instantaneous.
The best solution here should be to create an interface

```
public interface IWithHttpRequest {
    void onDataUpdate()
}
```

Make your activity implement `IWithHttpRequest`

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, IWithHttpRequest {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onDataUpdate() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

and in `ReadRss`, when you finished fetching data call

```
((IWithHttpRequest) context).onDataUpdate()
```

Comment: the Interface should be part of the Fragment Class ? 
and where should i implement it exactly ? in my Activity ( that provides the launch functionality for my different fragments ) or in my ReadRss Class ( That provides the Data Fetching Functionality ) ??

Comment: I updated my answer. The interface should be declared in a separate file (IWithHttpRequest.java)

Comment: ReadRss extends AsyncTask and i've overriden the 3 methods ( onPreExecute , doInBackground , onPostExecute ) i tried to past the last line you gave me in both onPostExecute and doInBackground and it did not work ! 
PS: i use progressDialog when the fragment is launched at the first place to fetch the data !

Comment: `((IWithHttpRequest) context).onDataUpdate();` should be called in **onPostExecute()**. Can you share you `ReadRss` class, and updated `HomeFragment`?

Comment: Can you confirm `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);` is called?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.essat.essat.Home cannot be cast to com.example.essat.essat.IWithHttpRequest i Get this now , after rebuilding the app

Comment: Did you change something else? because `context` should be an `HomeFragment` not `Home`.

Comment: i changed nothing , the code is as posted , i added the log messages and i found out that when it comes to onPostExecute it crashes

Comment: Do you have an Activity called `Home`?

Comment: i do , it contains different tabs , HomeFragment is one of them and passing getContext to ReadRss constructor should give an instance of HomeFragment i thought

Comment: You're right, you should make `ReadRss` take one more parameter of type `IWithHttpRequest`, then in **onRefresh()** update with `new ReadRss(getContext(), recyclerView, this).execute();`

Answer (score 1):

in order to refresh you should do this :

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.refreshContainer);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
      // refresh logic
       if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
}
```

You may also try to clear your data in recyclerview like this
YourAdapter.clearData();

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `setOnRefreshListener` for the `swipeRefreshLayout`.

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
```